# Jquery load() not working

Tags: jquery

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $('#list').change(function()
{
if ($(this).val() === 'College')
{
 $.ajax({
   url: 'ajax.php';
   success: function(data)
   {
   $('#content').html(data);
   }
 });
}
});
});
</script>


<select id="list">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="College">First</option>
<option value="Second">Second</opion>
<option value="Third">Third</option>
</select>
<div id='content'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The script should load the external file 'ajax.php' but it doesnt. I tried using alert('') instead of loading it and it runs fine but it just doesnt run the $.ajax.

Comment: Have you checked in the network? Any error?

Comment: Does it enter the success handler? If not, try adding one for error and investigating any returned errors.

Comment: Open the browser's JS console and look at the error message.

Comment: Code is wrong url: 'ajax.php'; you have to put a comma there instead of semicolon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have error in your ajax code, you have to put a comma after the url property `url: 'ajax.php';` instead of a semicolon.The code should be like

```
 $.ajax({
   url: 'ajax.php',
   success: function(data)
   {
   $('#content').html(data);
   }
 });
```

Try debugging for more errors.